# Is there anyway to make bulk of SMS/MMS?

Tags: android, sms, message, mms

I'm trying to make bulk of sms/mms now for testing my android message program.

(I need almost 5000 sms/mms messages, it's so big :-) )

So I made an app that access to sms/mms databas file directly, but it works so slowly

because it works on phone or emulator, limited hardware

so I want to ask you that how to make bulk of sms and mms messages for about 4~5 thousands.

can I make them easier through other way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to telnet to the emulator (on port 5554) and send the text:

```
sms send <NUMBER> <TEXT>
```

**Edit**

So if that works just make a small app that opens a tcp connection to that port and spams sms send commands.

From [anddev.org: Simulating incoming Phone Calls](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_simulating_incoming_phone_calls_-_sms_via_cmd-t135.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll using what u said :-)